# grep within a line, show unmatched pattern

Tags: grep

How do I grep within a line, and print the unmatched words?

For example, the line is something like `"  one    two  three "`.

What I want is anything that is not one, and trimmed (leading and trailing spaces (could be space or tabs) removed ).

In this case, how do i get `"two  three"`?

Answer (score 2):

using sed instead:

```
sed -r 's/\bone\b//g;s/^\s*|\s*$//g'
```

E.g.

```
kent$  echo "  one two three   "|sed -r 's/\bone\b//g;s/^\s*|\s*$//g'
two three
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sed instead:

```
sed -e 's/[ \t]*one[ \t]*//'
```